# WI-FI Printing in Windows 8 Metro App?

Tags: windows-8, printing, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, wifi

I am developing a C#/XAML Metro Application , in which i want to how can i achieve Wi - Fi Printing Programatically through code in from my METRO App.

From C#/XAML Metro app , i  want to detect what are the available Wi - Fi printers available in the present range of Wi -fi and connect to it and give a page for printing.

1) How can i achieve this , what are the various alternatives available to achieve this ??

2) Are there any API Avaliable to achieve this ??

Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to print document in background in Windows Store app. You must have go through device charm.